# Three js physical light go beyond wall

Tags: three.js

I'm new to Three js. Trying to implement physical lighting and I tried this example. [threejs_physical_light](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lights_physical.html)

My problem is, why light go beyond the brick wall? and how can I prevent that? (I have changed wall size in that example)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTuh7.png)

Comment: OP's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jonarya/sap848ao/

Comment: working version https://jsfiddle.net/jonarya/41qbdrug/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, "physical lights" in the three.js example you referenced refers to physically-based light intensity units and physically-based light attenuation. It has noting to do with the artifacts you are seeing.

The artifacts are present because the near plane of the frustum for the light's shadow camera is set at its default value of 0.5.

By default in three.js, shadows are cast by back-faces of objects. So once the light's position is closer than 0.5 units from the back-faces of the shadow-casting wall, you will see the artifacts you refer to.

three.js r.86

Comment: So if i want to attach the light source to the wall this value should be less than wall thickness. Am i correct? What property should i change for this?

Comment: 1. Yes.  2. `light.shadow.camera.near`. It must be greater than 0.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the second wall doesn't accept shadows... could you please show the code? Most importantly, how are lights and walls created.

Comment: I have added the link (threejs_physical_light) to the example. I did as you said with no luck.

Comment: In this particular example you linked you'd need to do this:

`boxMesh.receiveShadow = true; `

before it is added to the scene.

Comment: It is not working, I have created a jsfiddle with this. https://jsfiddle.net/jonarya/71jyhfsq/1/

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I am not sure what is wrong with this.
I've made a fiddle which illustrates the problem a bit more precisely... because the shadow GENERALLY works, except not if the light source is too close to an object. 

Bizzare.

https://jsfiddle.net/s9v761q8/

Comment: So, it seems this is a bug. doesn't it?

Comment: Could be. You'd need to ask someone much more experienced. I'd try posting a github issue on this.

Comment: I have raised it in github, https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/11909